# How can I add multiple product variations for the same product?

Tags: python, django

I have made product for clothing, and I want to have two variations of same product: size and color.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Product (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    active =models.BooleanField(default=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=120)

#For variation   
class Variation (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=CHOOSE_SIZE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

So far doing this I can only add one variation like I have added on white shirt on the product, I added variation for color for the shirt now how can I add variation for color.

here is my html code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} {{ object.title }} {#{{ object.variation_set.all }}#} 
<select class="form-control"> 
{% for vari_obj in object.variation_set.all %} 
    <option value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }} </option> 
{% endfor %} 
</select> 
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    active =models.BooleanField(default=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Variations(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=CHOOSE_SIZE)
    color = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Remove size from Products model.  Put size and color in Variations model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
 But i want to have independent choice for color and independent choice for size. How can i achieve so.

here is my html code
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{  object.title }}

{#{{ object.variation_set.all }}#}

    <select class="form-control">
        {% for vari_obj in object.variation_set.all %}
            <option value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

{% endblock %}

Comment: If it solved your problem you can check the arrow to accept the answer

Comment: put your template code in your question and format it as code so it can be understood.  Also include your view code